# How to check for Null (or other than value '1' , '2'') from position 68 to 69 in a Variable Block file. Records may end before position 27

Tags: mainframe, jcl, syncsort, easytrieve

I need to get the count for anything having value other than '1' or '2' in position 688.

IS it possible by Easytrieve or SORT in JCL ?
I have done it like this

-[ Character on 653 position should not be spaces AND ( CHeck 688 NE 1 .'AND'  688 NE '2']

```
 INCLUDE COND=
             ((653,5,CH,NE,C'     ',AND,((688,2,CH,NE,C '1 ',AND,688,2,CH,NE,C '2 ')))
```

can we do it in more efficient or other way ?

Comment: It's very difficult to determine what you're asking here.  What do you mean by NULL?  Do you mean x'00'?

Comment: Without seeing the records it is difficult to advise, also it is unclear what you are asking; what constitutes null - vb record ending before column 27, space, x'00' ???

Comment: Well, it can almost certainly be done, but as has been commented already, it is just unclear what you want to do. What exactly do you want? Records with less than 28 bytes of data? Any occurence of X'00' in first 27 bytes of data? Any occurrence of some other value?

Comment: You've changed the question radically, you need to change the title as well. Can any records be shorter than the fields being tested for?

Comment: I see now that you did update the title, although still equally difficult as a title. OK, so you can have short records. Updating answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify human understanding by using OMIT instead of INCLUDE, to get rid of your negative conditions.

```
OPTION COPY,VLSCMP
OMIT COND=(653,5,CH,EQ,C' ',
         OR,
           688,2,CH,EQ,C '1 ',
         OR,
           688,2,CH,EQ,C '2 ')
```

It would be possible to use field-type SS to contract the tests on position 688, but I'd be wary of that if your data is suspect (only use SS when you are sure of what values there may be).

It could be simplified, to my mind, by using SORT symbols to avoid the repetition, and errors that can go with that.

Since you have short records which may get in the way (cause a failure of the step) I have included OPTION VLSCMP. This will pad all fields on INCLUDE/OMIT which are not contained within a record (because the record is short) with binary zeros. Thus, all records with space at 653,5 will be dropped, all records which are not C'1 ' or C'2 ' at 688,2 will be dropped. All short records will be included, as the criteria for dropping will not be met (fields will be binary zeros for the comparison on INCLUDE/OMIT). A short record which does contain space at 653,5 will be omitted. If this is not what you want, that can be dealt with by extending the conditions.

If you need a formatted count that can easily be done, but if you are just investigating, it could easily be the case that the default counts in the sysout give you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to count the number of records matching a criteria in either sort or easytrieve

1. Easytrieve - very easy have a look at the manual - https://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=hUBnU-XbCOfC8gep74GIBg#q=easytrieve+manual
2. Most sort utilities have some sort of reporting funvtions that could be used, for DFSort there is the count (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.icea100/ice1ca40124.htm) option in IceTool.
   Even with out the reporting functions it can be done using in a 2 step process

   - Select the required records and reformat and include a binary field (with the value 1 using the outrec see http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.icea100%2Fice1ca50263.htm
   - Sort sum the file from the first step

   The sort is roughly:

```
    //STEP1    EXEC PGM=SORT                                       
    //SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=H                                         
    //SORTIN   DD DSN=INP1,DISP=SHR,UNIT=3380,VOL=SER=SCR001       
    //SORTOUT  DD DSN=&&OUTPUT,DISP=(,PASS),UNIT=3390,             
    //   SPACE=(CYL,(5,1)),DCB=(LRECL=22)                          
    //SYSIN    DD *                                                
      OPTION COPY
      OMIT COND=(653,5,CH,EQ,C' ',
             OR,
               688,2,CH,EQ,C '1 ',
             OR,
               688,2,CH,EQ,C '2 ')       
      OUTREC BUILD=(1,4,X'0000000001')  
    //*
    //STEP1    EXEC PGM=SORT                                       
    //SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=H                                         
    //SORTIN   DD DSN=&&OUTPUT,DISP=SHR,UNIT=3380,VOL=SER=SCR001       
    //SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                    
    //SYSIN    DD *
     SORT FIELDS=(5,1,BI)
     SUM FIELDS=(6,4,BI)
     OUTREC BUILD=(6,4,BI,TO=ZD,LENGTH=9)
```

There will be areas you can improve

Comment: You don't need two steps with the reporting functions. I think we can still assume it is a VB, so 1,4 must be the RDW. Frankly, if the count is all that is needed, the sysout for the first step is going to be enough. I was thinking since the data is shot SORT would be more flexible than ICETOOL, but otherwise COUNT does what it says on the box (and complexity can be dealt with using `USING`). As I'm even less sure about the question, didn't want to go too far...

Comment: Gave a bit of a tidy. You can't overlap a SUM field with a SORT key. Made the intermediate a VB.

Comment: Changed to not sort on RDW, COUNT works on DFSort, not sure about SYNC-SORT (It did not the last time I used it). The sort only version should work with all Mainframe-Sort's + I think it is handy knowing about all the things you can do with sort.

Comment: I think current SyncSort has `COUNT`. For the SORT-only version, `SUM` is not needed. `SUM` always requires SORTing the file (or using `MERGE` with a single input). Using the OUTFIL reporting functions, `REMOVECC` and `TRAILER1` with `COUNT`, it can be done in one step with no `SORT`. Yes, good to know what is quickly available.